# Cypher Query for Char Node Property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I declared using SDN (spring data neo4j) a char property in java

```
@NodeEntity
public class Psite {

    @GraphId
    Long id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
     public String identifier;
     public char amino;
```

However I cannot perform any queries regarding this property on browser of neo4j server.

All three cases below give me 0 results.

```
MATCH (n:`Psite`) WHERE n.amino = "T" RETURN n LIMIT 25

MATCH (n:`Psite` {amino : 'T'}) RETURN n LIMIT 25

MATCH (n:`Psite` {amino : "T"}) RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

Can somebody help me please

Comment: how is it returned if you do `match (p:Psite {identifier:"foo"}) return p.amino` ?

Comment: Can you try to compare with the ascii code ? `WHERE n.amino = 84` just curious

Comment: [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/property-values-detailed.html) say a char is stored as a 16 bit unsigned int (`char | 16-bit unsigned integers representing Unicode characters | u0000 to uffff (0 to 65535)`), which is the Java char. I've never stored a char from SDN, but like Michael says I'd try comparing it as an int, i.e. 84. Does that work?

Comment: Yes the answer is comparing this with  ascii code WHERE n.amino = 84 works great!!! Thanks Michael for your immediate reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments above the best solution so far is:

```
MATCH (n:`Psite`) WHERE n.amino = 84 RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

instead of

```
MATCH (n:`Psite`) WHERE n.amino = "T" RETURN n LIMIT 25
```

i.e. replace "T" with its int ASCII value.